# Creating a text editor in a bubble shape in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

In my project, I need to show the related code piece in a bubble shape, when a user clicks on a UML Class diagram. The bubble shape, which contains the source code, must be editable so the user can make changes on the source code and when the user finish editing the code, I will update the UML class diagram in order to keep the code and diagram synchronised. You can check the following mock-up to understand the scenario:

[image: Scenario]

However, I don't have a deep knowledge in JavaFX and FXML. Therefore, I don't know how should I create these bubbles and which elements or shapes might correspond my requirements. Should I show the source code by using  element?

Comment: So what is your question? Whether to show or how to show the bubbles?

Comment: @ThomasKilian How should I construct these bubbles?

Comment: Ok. In that case I'll remove the UML tag, since this is a pure Java-XXX question.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yeah, you are totally right.

Comment: StackPane with a picture of bubble shape and a textArea. I would create class BubbleShape  extends stackpane. I would setTextAreaText(String text) and setLocation(double x, double y).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437411/how-to-put-a-text-into-a-circle-object-to-display-it-from-circles-center.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258605/javafx-how-can-i-best-place-a-label-centered-in-a-shape?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed a bunch of code from different places and did not clean it up.
This is a sloppy/quick implementation, but it's a start. It's clickable and editable.

> BubbleShape.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class BubbleShape extends StackPane {

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    ImageView bubbleShape;

    BubbleShape(String text)
    {
        textArea.setText(text);
        textArea.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        textArea.setMaxSize(200, 200);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        File file = new File("bubble_shape.png");
        if (file.exists())
        {
            bubbleShape = new ImageView(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
            bubbleShape.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                    alert.setTitle("Exception Dialog");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Exception Dialog");
                    alert.setContentText("Could not find file blabla.txt!");

                    Label label = new Label("The exception stacktrace was:");

                    TextArea tempTextArea = new TextArea();
                    tempTextArea.setEditable(true);
                    tempTextArea.setWrapText(true);

                    tempTextArea.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    tempTextArea.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    GridPane.setVgrow(tempTextArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
                    GridPane.setHgrow(tempTextArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

                    GridPane expContent = new GridPane();
                    expContent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    expContent.add(label, 0, 0);
                    expContent.add(tempTextArea, 0, 1);

                    alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(expContent);

                    alert.showAndWait();
                    textArea.setText(tempTextArea.getText());
                }
            });

            textArea.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                    alert.setTitle("Exception Dialog");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Exception Dialog");
                    alert.setContentText("Could not find file blabla.txt!");

                    Label label = new Label("The exception stacktrace was:");

                    TextArea tempTextArea = new TextArea();
                    tempTextArea.setEditable(true);
                    tempTextArea.setWrapText(true);

                    tempTextArea.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    tempTextArea.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    GridPane.setVgrow(tempTextArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
                    GridPane.setHgrow(tempTextArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

                    GridPane expContent = new GridPane();
                    expContent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    expContent.add(label, 0, 0);
                    expContent.add(tempTextArea, 0, 1);

                    // Set expandable Exception into the dialog pane.
                    alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(expContent);

                    alert.showAndWait();
                    textArea.setText(tempTextArea.getText());
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File does not exits1");
        }

        this.getChildren().addAll(textArea, bubbleShape);
    }
}
```

> Main.java

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication14 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    AnchorPane apMain;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
         BubbleShape bs = new BubbleShape("Hello world!");
         bs.setLayoutX(50.0);
         bs.setLayoutY(50.0);

         BubbleShape bs2 = new BubbleShape("Bye world!");
         bs2.setLayoutX(400);
         bs2.setLayoutY(400);
         apMain.getChildren().addAll(bs, bs2);
    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="apMain" prefHeight="749.0" prefWidth="973.0" stylesheets="@makeTextAreaTransparent.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication14.FXMLDocumentController">

</AnchorPane>
```

> CSS: makeTextAreaTransparent.css

```
.text-area {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(53,89,119,0.4);
}

.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.text-area .scroll-pane .viewport{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}


.text-area .scroll-pane .content{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

[image]